# undefined references in Eclipse CDT

Tags: linker

I've searched alot for a solution to this problem but in vain so to the problem I'm using Eclipse IDE MARS (4.5.2) release and I've been working into separating my classes to header and .cpp files.

**node.h**

```
#ifndef NODE_H_
#define NODE_H_


template <typename T>
class node {
    T key;
    node<T> *next;
public:
    node(T k, node<T> *a_node) : key(k), next(a_node) {}

    T get_key() const;
    void set_key(T key);
    node<T>* get_next() const;
    void set_next(node<T> *next);

    ~node();
};


#endif /* NODE_H_ */
```

**node.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "node.h"

template<typename T>
T node<T>::get_key() const {
    return key;
}
template<typename T>
void node<T>::set_key(T key) {
    this->key = key;
}
template<typename T>
node<T>* node<T>::get_next() const {
    return next;
}
template<typename T>
void node<T>::set_next(node<T> *next) {
    this->next = next;
}
template<typename T>
node<T>::~node() {
    std::cout << "Node destructor" << std::endl;
}
```

**singly_linked_list.h**

```
#ifndef SINGLY_LINKED_LIST_H_
#define SINGLY_LINKED_LIST_H_

#include <iostream>
template <typename T> class node;  // forward declare our template

template <typename T>
class linked_list {
    node<T> *head;
    node<T> *tail;
    int num_elements;
public:
    linked_list() : head(nullptr), tail(head), num_elements(0) {}; //O(1)
    void push_front(T key);     // O(1)
    T top_front();  // O(1)
    void pop_front();   // O(1)
    void push_back(T key);  // O(1)
    T top_back();   // O(1)
    void pop_back();    // O(n)
    node<T> * find(T key);  // O(n)
    void erase(T key);  // O(n) , only used to erase elements between front and back
    void add_before(node<T> * const a_node,T key);  // O(n)
    void add_after(node<T> * const a_node,T key);   // O(1) , finding the a_node takes O(n) by find method
    bool empty(); // O(1)
    void print(); // O(n)
    int size(); // O(1)
    ~linked_list();  // O(n)
};

#endif /* SINGLY_LINKED_LIST_H_ */
```

**singly_linked_list.cpp**

```
template <typename T>
void linked_list<T>::push_front(T key) {
    node<T> *new_node = new node<T> (key,nullptr);
    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = new_node;
        tail = new_node ;
    }else {
        new_node->set_next(head);
        head = new_node;
    }
    num_elements++;
}

template <typename T>
T linked_list<T>::top_front() {
    if (head == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Empty List!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    } else {
        return head->get_key();
    }
}

template <typename T>
void linked_list<T>::pop_front() {
    if (head == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Empty List!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    } else {
        node<T> *temp = head;
        head = temp->get_next();
        delete temp;
        temp = nullptr;
        num_elements--;
    }
    if (head == nullptr) tail = head;
}

template<typename T>
void linked_list<T>::push_back(T key) {
    node<T> *new_node = new node<T>(key,nullptr);
    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = new_node;
        tail = new_node;
    }else {
        tail->set_next(new_node);
        tail = new_node;
    }
    num_elements++;
}

template<typename T>
T linked_list<T>::top_back() {
    if (head == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Empty List!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }else {
        return tail->get_key();
    }
}

template<typename T>
void linked_list<T>::pop_back() {
    if (head == nullptr) { // no elements
        std::cerr << "Empty List!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    if (head == tail) { // only one element
        node<T> *temp = head;
        head = nullptr;
        tail = head;
        delete temp;
        num_elements--;
    }else {
        node<T> *temp = head;
        while (temp->get_next()->get_next() != nullptr) {
            temp = temp->get_next();
        }
        tail = temp;
        tail->set_next(nullptr);
        temp = temp->get_next();
        delete temp;
        num_elements--;
    }
}

template <typename T>
bool linked_list<T>::empty() {
    if ((head == nullptr) && (num_elements == 0)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void linked_list<T>::print() {
    if (head == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Empty List!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    } else {
        node<T> *temp = head;
        while(temp != nullptr) {
            std::cout << temp->get_key() << " " ;
            temp = temp->get_next();
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

    }
}

template<typename T>
int linked_list<T>::size() {
    return num_elements;
}

template<typename T>
node<T>* linked_list<T>::find(T key) {
    if (head == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Empty List!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    } else {
        node<T> *temp = head;
        while(temp != nullptr) {
            if (temp->get_key() == key) {
                return temp;
            }
            temp = temp->get_next();
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
void linked_list<T>::erase(T key) {         // only used to erase elements between front and back
    if (head == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Empty List!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }else {
        node<T> *temp = head;
        if (head == tail) {
            if (temp->get_key() == key) {
                delete temp;
                head = nullptr;
                tail = head;
            }
        } else {
            node<T> *pre;
            while(temp != nullptr) {
                if (temp->get_key() == key) {
                    break;
                }
                pre = temp;
                temp = temp->get_next();
            }
            pre->set_next(temp->get_next());
            delete temp;
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
void linked_list<T>::add_before(node<T>* const a_node, T key) {
    if (head == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "head is null" << std::endl;
    }else if (a_node == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "the node doesn't exist" << std::endl;
    }else {
        node<T> * new_node = new node<T>(key,nullptr);
        node<T> *temp = head;
        while (temp->get_next() != a_node) {
            temp = temp->get_next();
        }
        new_node->set_next(a_node);
        temp->set_next(new_node);
        if (head == a_node) {
            head = new_node;
        }
        num_elements++;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void linked_list<T>::add_after(node<T>* const a_node, T key) { // add after a node in the middle not the fron and the back
    if (head == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "head is null" << std::endl;
    }else if (a_node == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "the node doesn't exist" << std::endl;
    }else {
        node<T> * new_node = new node<T>(key,nullptr);
        new_node->set_next(a_node->get_next());
        a_node->set_next(new_node);
        if (tail == a_node) {
            tail = new_node;
        }
        num_elements++;
    }
}

template<typename T>
linked_list<T>::~linked_list() {
    node<T> *temp = head;
    node<T> *temp_pre = temp;
    while (temp->get_next() != nullptr) {
        temp = temp->get_next();
        delete temp_pre;
        temp_pre = temp;
    }
    delete temp;
}
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "singly_linked_list.h"


int main() {
    linked_list<std::string> ll;

    /*   back operations     */
    ll.top_back();
    ll.push_back("A");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that all the methods of the linked_list class are undefined referenced while all the header and cpp files are in same project. Any help would be very much appreciated.

**Edit:**

I've tried to link only the node class the and the problem still persists.
the linker is as follows:

```
g++ -o Working.exe node.o singly_linked_list.o test_singly_linked_list.o
```

Comment: Have you include your directories with *.cpp and *.h to _Project settings -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> MCU GCC Compiler -> Includes_?

Comment: @imbearr I think  it isn't a problem in the compilation, please check the edit, and yes I've tried to explicitly add the project working directory to the includes of the compiler but it didn't help.